# DRF adding images to a ForeignKey already in the database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am looking to add Images, to a Listing(ForeignKey), which will already be in my database.

I have an Image model..

```
class Image(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=get_image_filename)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

ImageSerializer

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    photo = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('url', 'photo', 'listing', )

   def create(self, data):
    listing, __ = Listing.objects.get_or_create(listing=data["listing"])
    return Image(photo=data["photo"], listing=listing)
```

ImageViewSet

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    detail_serializer_class = ImageDetailSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    '''Show detailed Image view'''

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            if hasattr(self, 'detail_serializer_class'):
                return self.detail_serializer_class
        return super(ImageViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
```

I have tried overriding the create method in the serializer, and perform_create method in the actual viewset. But keep running into errors. Any advice in the right direction would be awesome[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBhzk.png)

## FieldError at /api/v1/images/

Cannot resolve keyword 'listing' into field. Choices are: address, airconditioning, amenities, approximate_square_footage, basement, city, community, description, exteriorhouse, garages, heating, hoa, house_levels, id, image, latitude, listprice, longitude, lot_size, numberbedrooms, numberfullbaths, numberhalfbaths, outbuildings, propertyviews, pub_date, roof_type, roomtotal, schools, style_house, taxes, taxmap, type_house, unfinished_square_footage, user, user_id, water, yearbuilt, zipcode, zoning

## Edit

changed create method to...

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    listing_data = validated_data.pop('listing')
    image = Image.objects.create(**validated_data)
    image.listing =Listing.objects.get(photo=image, 
                                       listing_data=listing_data)
    return image
```

Now the error...

save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Comment: Please, share your model `Listing`

Comment: The Listing model has a whole bunch of static info, bedrooms, bath, etc. The ImageModel is the model that has the ForeignKey to the listing model.

Comment: In fact, I believe your problem lies on calling `get_or_create` over model `Listing`

Comment: I edited the Post, now encountering a new error.